# Drupal 7 views view template

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

in my viewv-view-fields--myView.tpl.php
i have styled how i want the output to look like

```
if(isset($fields['title']) && isset($fields['file'])) { 
    $category = $fields['field_category']->content;
    $file_link = $fields['file']->raw; 
    $title = $fields['title']->content; 

if($category == "2014"){    

    print '<tr><td><a href="'.$file_link.'">'.$title.'</a> </td> </tr>';

} else if($category == "2013") {
    print '<tr><td><a href="'.$file_link.'">'.$title.'</a> </td> </tr>';
}
```

i can if i want output only one category white my ifs
but now to the trouble if i want to output category 2014 in one table and category 2013 i another.

in my views-view--myView.tpl.php i can only do print rows and it picks both, i tried to put the links into a array but it creates a new array of every link so im kinda stuck here

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>2014</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if ($rows): 
            print $rows;
        ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>2013</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <?php if ($rows): 
            print $rows;
        ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

anyone how got a suggestion?

Comment: can you not use, from within the drupal ui, the table output? then if im not mistaken, you can group your results by a certain field value, so in your case year. Order your results by year descending, then it should be exactly hwo you want it. No need for template alterting etc etc etc

Comment: Nice one Goon3r, I must have missed that feature thanks for the eye opener